# redirect 301 anything in a directory to a new domain with different url structure

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following URL structure that I need 301'd to a new URL structure.

```
www.olddomain.com/perfumed/p1
www.olddomain.com/perfumed/p2
www.olddomain.com/perfumed/box/p1
www.olddomain.com/perfumed/box/p2
```

I want to redirect all products and folders under `perfumed` category to go to my new domain:

```
www.newdomain.com/glossy
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be in a `.htaccess` (assuming you have access to it since you have it tagged):

```
Redirect 301 /perfumed https://www.newdomain.com/glossy
```

This should keep your structure after `perfumed` intact.